# Is Malenkov wearing some sort of uniform in this picture?

Tags: soviet-union, clothing, uniform

Or just a mildly ridiculous sailor suit?[image]

He is the third from the right.

Comment: Fashion of the day? http://www.gettyimages.ae/detail/news-photo/vyacheslav-molotov-nikita-khrushchev-and-joseph-stalin-on-news-photo/170983120#vyacheslav-molotov-nikita-khrushchev-and-joseph-stalin-on-the-rostrum-picture-id170983120

Comment: Looks more like a chef's outfit than a sailor suit to me... though I echo the mildly ridiculous sentiment.  Perhaps he lost a bet.

Comment: Whats the source?

Comment: @AnnaCHOI I no longer remember... But it's all over the internet...

Answer (score 6):

1. Listing of the people in the pic (just FYI): -- they constitute the closest and highest circle of Stalin's minions --

   - Anastas Mikoyan (ministry of trade/industry),
   - Nikita Khruschev (Moscow Party first secretary),
   - Iosif Stalin (the boss himself),
   - Georgiy Malenkov (vice-premier, Stalin's deputy),
   - Lavrentiy Beria (chief of NKVD, various other posts),
   - Vyacheslav Molotov (ministry of foreign affairs etc).

Photo taken (most likely) at some point in 1949 (Khruschev moved from Kiev to Moscow in 1949, and Molotov was demoted in 1949).

2. The main idea was to wear a suit which was close enough to a military attire that Stalin was sporting. So it might look a bit ridiculous to us now but...
3. So this kind of clothing was very popular at the time. Here is more pics of the same sort

[Some party members in Orenburg](http://orenpolit.ru/media/k2/items/cache/488ff8b5b009d002d059b5e5265e9f96_XL.jpg)

[Malenkov and Beria on Lenin's Mausoleum](http://orenpolit.ru/images/11-Pz-24.110301.jpg)